# Assigning data member field/property variable of type T

Tags: c#

Why does the assignment statement

```
_t = new Y();
```

cause the following compiler error?

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Y' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public class X { }
public class Y { }
public class A<T> { }    
public class B<T> : A<X> where T : Y, new()
{
    private T _t;

    public B()
    {
        _t = new T();
        _t = new Y();  //compiler error
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler error itself tells you exactly why...

Comment: I'm given the same error with an explicit cast.

Comment: T is a subclass of Y. You could assign a T to a reference to Y, because as a subclass of Y, a T IS a Y -- but not the reverse. T is a *superset* of Y. It's everything Y is, and more. A Y doesn't have the "more". It's not a T.

Comment: That's because a `Y` is a `Y`, it's not a `T` and there's no way (that the compiler knows of) to turn it into one.

Comment: To put it more plainly, you just tried to put an `Animal` in to a variable declared as a `Dog`.

Comment: @SamusArin I definitely DO NOT get the same error with an explicit cast.

Comment: @Servy *"That's because a Y is a Y, it's not a T"* I thought the **`where`** constraint told the compiler that T "can be" a Y?

Comment: @SamusArin Why do you people make up these bizarre stories? Read the documentation. Google it and read it. Your imagination is not an authoritative source of information about C# or any other programming language. "Hi, I had a beer and made up some weird story off the top of my head, and now the compiler tells me I'm wrong. Why is the compiler broken?" It isn't.

Comment: @SamusArin Yes, T *is* a Y.  Y isn't a T though.

Comment: @Servy He doesn't know what "is" means, in this context.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I didn't see a reason to repeat what you had already defined it as.  Had you not already defined it, I would have.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough.

Comment: @Servy The compiler appears to be saying "cannot implicitly convert b/c an explicit conversion exists *(what conversion, a cast?)* maybe you are missing a cast". That's a bit confusing to me, maybe you can reword it for me?

Comment: @SamusArin, `T` can be a any type that derives from `Y`. It can be Y itself, it can also be any potentially existing (or in a future time existing) SubClassFromY (i.e., `public class SubClassFromY : Y {}`). Now, you can't do `SubClassFromY _t = new Y();`, or can you? Hence the compiler complaining...

Comment: @SamusArin It's saying it cannot implicitly convert it.  It also asks if you perhaps meant to explicitly convert it.  You didn't.  It's a common problem, hence the hint, but in your case an explicit conversion isn't going to succeed either, even though one exists.  In your code there *is* no way to convert it, unless you know something about the types in question not shown.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I had that working ok, but the problem is I wanted to store into a data member of T. I'm totally abusing the intention of generics (using a type enum and everything), but I don't have time to do an entire refactor right now, I just wanted to get things one step closer an inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T x = (T)new Y()` is the explicit conversion. It will work at runtime if and only if `T` is actually `Y`. If `T` is any subclass of `Y`, it'll throw an exception. So don't ever do that with a generic type argument -- if your class is going to require `T` to actually always be `Y`, it shouldn't be generic. It should just use `Y`.

`T` is a type parameter. A parameter that has only one permissible value isn't a parameter. It's a constant.

```
public class Y
{
    public int YStuff;
}

public class YSubclass : Y
{
    public int YSubclassStuff;
}

public class Generic<T> where T : Y, new() {
    public static void Test() {
        //  NEVER DO THIS, EVER
        T x = (T)new Y();
    }
}
```

The `where Y` constraint says that any type you use for `T` must be `Y` or a subclass of `Y`. It could a subclass of `Y` that adds ten other things. If `T` is `YSubclass`, a `Y` *is not that thing*. It's only part of that thing.

You can't do this:

```
Y y = new Y();
var x = y.YSubclassStuff;
```

`Y` doesn't have that field. You can't pretend a `Y` is a `YSubclass`. It *isn't*. This is not just "bad form" or a "shortcut" something; it's *impossible*.

...

```
public static void Main()
{
    //  OK
    Generic<Y>.Test();

    //  System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 
    //  'WpfApp1.Y' to type 'WpfApp1.YSubclass'.'
    //  And that's why what I did in Test() is a really, really bad idea
    //  and you should never do it. 
    Generic<YSubclass>.Test();
}
```

You need to solve your problem using virtual methods or interfaces. Those are the safe, acceptable ways to get there from here.

You can require that T implement a given interface, for example:

```
public interface Z
{
    void F();
}

public class Generic<T> where T : Y, Z, new()
```

Now you can create a `T`, whatever it may be, and guarantee that any `T` has `F()`.

Comment: Doing this is just wrong.  If you're going to write the code such that the generic method fails any time `T` isn't `Y` then the method simply shouldn't be generic.

Comment: @Servy I didn't say it was a good idea. But maybe I should explicitly say it's a godawful idea.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks for freeing me from the matrix with this tracer program :)

Comment: @SamusArin Now you've succeeded in turning your program from one that doesn't compile into one that always crashes every single time you run it.  You'd be better of having the program not compile, as then you'd at least know it doesn't work.

Comment: @SamusArin I hope you're not doing the unsafe cast. That's an indescribably bad idea. I merely threw that in to illustrate what the error message meant. It is not a solution to your problem.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Note that Samus' response is exactly why this is a bad answer, you're just encouraging the OP to actually use it.

Comment: @Servy (and Ed) What if i put in the constraint list the three specific types I need? They are currently implementing interfaces, but it defined for view-ing purposes. I now need to read/write to the DAL. I could either define another interface that they can implement, or see if I can maybe alter the existing one. The original interface was also kindof a hack b/c of the inability of multiple inheritance and one of the three classes already having a parent (they are all "Attachment" classes, AttachmentX, AttachmentY and AttachmentZ. AttachmentX : BaseRecord, so I couldn't make a BaseAttachment.

Comment: @SamusArin Use a common interface.

Comment: @Servy This is just a stepping stone for now. I don't have time for a full refactor. Eventually a lot of my code base will be rewritten. It's a great quick fix for my situation, but I see your point.

Comment: @SamusArin Are you doing the unsafe cast? Is that what you're saying? Do I misunderstand you? That's not a solution. That's just a silly way to make your program crash.

Comment: @SamusArin Making your program crash every single time you run it isn't "a quick fix".  It's just pretending that you don't have a problem when you still have exactly the same problem, except now you don't *realize* that you still have exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Servy I thought it would only crash for children of Y? I was going to use `class Generic<T> where : Y1, Y2, Y3, new()`. I'm already encoding the type-id for each, so I can call their corresponding DAL repos.

Comment: @SamusArin Please un-accept the answer so I can delete it. You did not understand what I told you. I don't think what you're now describing is even going to compile, but in any case I want no part of it.

Comment: @SamusArin It will crash any time `T` isn't `Y`.  If `T` is *always* `Y`, then *there's no reason for the method to be generic*, just use `Y` instead of `T`.

Comment: I need to reread it, sorry I skipped breakfast AND lunch... I'll un-accept when I read it quick after lunch, ok?

Comment: @SamusArin You should only accept answers *after* you know that they work, not *before*.  Accepting an answer and then only ever unaccepting the answer after testing it and seeing that it *won't* work is counter-productive for all of the people who see the accepted answer before you start testing it and assume that your question was answered, or that it would be a good idea for them to use this answer.

Comment: @EdPlunkett If you flag the post for a mod, they typically honor requests of a post author to delete an accepted answer they later realized has problems and that they would rather be deleted, so you could try that, if you want.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ok, all set. Thanks for help.

Comment: @SamusArin You're doing the interface?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have to, can't specify multiple types in constraint list. Why would a multi-inheritance type hierarchy exist in the `where` constraint if it doesn't exist anywhere else. Wishful thinking i guess.

Comment: Oh, right, right -- I wasn't thinking. There's no way an "inherits from A and B" constraint would make sense in a single-inheritance language. And constraining `T` to derive from class A *or* class B makes even less sense.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I just got my first sample of interface potential the other day trying to unify this same code I'm working on. It was a good day :)

Comment: @SamusArin Well, if you did get this resolved using interfaces as I suggested, then we're all on the same page now and you can accept the answer. Unless your code isn't actually working yet, as Servy suggests.

Comment: @EdPlunkett It worked on in my sample program, so it should elsewhere... I also started reading the language spec... should've went to the website for this, it uses a lot of snippets from the spec.

Comment: Well, the language spec may be overkill. But MSDN is great for stuff like `where`.